# Call a function from its name as a string in f#

Tags: f#, quotations

I thought that I might be able to do this with quotations - but I can't see how.

Should I just use a table of the functions with their names - or is their a way of doing this?

Thanks.

For more info......

I'm calling a lot of f# functions from excel and I wondered if I could write a f# function

let fs_wrapper (f_name:string) (f_params:list double) = 
    this bit calls fname with f_params

and then use

=fs_wrapper("my_func", 3.14, 2.71)

in the sheet rather than wrap all the functions separately.

Comment: Can you show a bit more of what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll need to use standard .NET Reflection to do this. Quotations aren't going to help, because they represent function calls using standard .NET `MethodInfo`, so you'll need to use reflection anyway. The only benefit of quotations (compared to naive reflection) is that you can compile them, which could give you better performance (but the compilation isn't perfect).

Depending on your specific scenario (e.g. where are the functions located), you'd have to do something like:

```
module Functions =
  let sin x = sin(x)
  let sqrt y = sqrt(y)

open System.Reflection

let moduleInfo = 
  Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
  |> Seq.find (fun t -> t.Name = "Functions")

let name = "sin"
moduleInfo.GetMethod(name).Invoke(null, [| box 3.1415 |])
```

Unless you need some extensibility or have a large number of functions, using a dictionary containing string as a key and function value as the value may be an easier option:

```
let funcs = 
  dict [ "sin", Functions.sin;
         "sqrt", Functions.sqrt ]

funcs.[name](3.1415)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works well. I may as well pass the module name as a string as well. The next thing is parameter type management, but I'll leave this for a while. What's the 'box' for?

Comment: @b1g3ar5 - The `Invoke` method takes arguments as array of objects (`obj[]`) because it cannot know the actual type of parameters. The `box` operation runs `float` value into `obj` value. The type of `[| 3.14 |]` would be `float[]`, which wouldn't match the expected type.

Comment: All this syntactical blah is making me miss Python/Ruby.  Even C# with dynamic, if you haveta.

Comment: @GregC - You can use the F# dynamic operator `?` and write something like `funcs?sin(3.14)` if you want to. All this syntactics blah can be, of course, hidden inside a simple function.

Comment: Any reason to use `GetTypes` and enumerate the result, rather than to use `GetType`?

Answer (score 2):

There are many methods but one way is to use Reflection, for instance:

```
typeof<int>.GetMethod("ToString", System.Type.EmptyTypes).Invoke(1, null)
typeof<int>.GetMethod("Parse", [|typeof<string>|]).Invoke(null, [|"112"|])
```

GetMethod optionally takes an array of types that define the signature, but you can skip that if your method is unambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

Following up on what Thomas alluded to, have a look at [Using and Abusing the F# Dynamic Lookup Operator](http://weblogs.asp.net/podwysocki/archive/2010/02/05/using-and-abusing-the-f-dynamic-lookup-operator.aspx) by Matthew Podwysocki.  It offers a syntactically clean way for doing dynamic lookup in F#.